# translate3d on firefox (moz) and safari (webkit)

Tags: php, html, translate3d

how can I add some code so that my `translate3d effect` also works on `firefox.` The jquery code is:

```
if (st > lastScrollTop){
```

$('div#search-apartments #content-inner #search-box').attr('style', '-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, '+movepx+'px, 0)');

} else {

$('div#search-apartments #content-inner #search-box').attr('style', '-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, '+movepx+'px, 0)');

So how and where do I need to add the code for `"-**moz**-transform:translate3d(0, '+movepx+'px, 0)"`??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code this will help you to solve for firefox also

$('div#search-apartments #content-inner #search-box').attr('style', '-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, '+movepx+'px, 0);-**moz**-transform:translate3d(0, '+movepx+'px, 0)');

Answer (score 0):

**USE THIS**

```
if (st > lastScrollTop){

    $('div#search-apartments #content-inner #search-box').css({'-webkit-transform':'translate3d(0, '+movepx+'px, 0)','-moz-transform:translate3d(0, '+movepx+'px, 0)'});
} else {

    $('div#search-apartments #content-inner #search-box').css({'-webkit-transform':'translate3d(0, '+movepx+'px, 0)','-moz-transform:translate3d(0, '+movepx+'px, 0)'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.

Alex, yours didn't work somehow but Sohail, yours works perfectly. I just extended your solution for IE and Opera and made this out of it:

`$('div#search-apartments #content-inner #search-box').attr('style', '-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, '+movepx+'px, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0, '+movepx+'px, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0, '+movepx+'px, 0);-o-transform:translate3d(0, '+movepx+'px, 0)');`

Again, thank you